# Is this correct regarding subtraction and addition of numbers or functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let us say we have

$$2=2$$

Then I would do is $$2-2=0$$*i.e.* I shifted $2$ from RHS to LHS. Now, my textbook says that this is not true and is a wrong concept. What my textbook tells me is this:

> $$ 2-2=2-2$$

This means that when two equalities are equal , we cannot shift one from RHS to LHS but can subtract the same amount on both sides.

$$f(x) = g(x) \implies f(x)-g(x) = g(x)-g(x)$$

So, I wanted to confirm if this is how we really do it or both the methods are correct?

Comment: Uh... that seems like its just semantics.  If you have $a=b$ it follows that $a-b=0$... whether you phrased that colloquially as "shifting from one side to the other" or whether you phrased it as "*right cancellation property of addition*" or whether you phrased it as "subtraction" doesn't matter... they all have the same effect.  They aren't really different methods, they are just different ways of explaining the effect.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok. Is shifting from one side to the other only used for explaining concept but is wrong in terms.

Comment: Now... I will warn you to keep in mind that in some more abstract contexts, it matters whether something was on the right side of an expression versus the left.  For example, matrices.  You might have $A=BC$ and you might think to multiply by $C^{-1}$ to effectively move the $C$ around.  If we were to multiply $C^{-1}$ on the right we get $AC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$ which simplifies to $AC^{-1}=B$.  If we were to multiply on the left however we get $C^{-1}A=C^{-1}BC$ which did not simplify.  We must be consistent which side we do things on, we weren't allowed to do $C^{-1}A=B$, that is incorrect

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok got it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, and is more commonly known as **transposition**.

---

Well, in most textbooks, it is introduced as:

> Adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing (not by zero) on both sides doesn't affect its truth. So, $a=b$ is equivalent to
> $$a-b=b-b\implies a-b=0$$

Then, the next section tells that

> For the sake of convenience, we do the same in one-step by saying that we moved $b$ from RHS to LHS, and changed its sign as we moved it. *This is called transposition.*

---

So yes, maybe the book will introduce it later, or probably not. But **it is correct**. In higher classes, you wouldn't be spending your time and space into writing that "extra line". At this stage, if it isn't introduced to you, nonetheless, I suggest to *not use it*.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Can you use it in case of functions also.

Comment: Of course! But there are two limitations: 1. As @JMoravitz said, in conditions where order is significant, make sure that you respect the order, and 2. You cannot use it (wholly) in case of inequations.

Comment: Ok.Thanks . . ..

Comment: How did you make the text yellow

Comment: Where did I make it yellow? For **bold**, use ```**text**``` and for _italic_, use ```_text_```.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, let $R$ be a commutative ring like the ring of integers.

Subtraction is defined in terms of addition (so its a derived operation):

$r - s  := r+(-s)$

i.e., the subtraction $r-s$ means that you add $r$ and $-s$, the additive inverse of $s$.

E.g. $3 - 2 = 3 +(-2) = 1$.